# c# pasting contents of word document into winforms control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Is there a way to paste a particular word document's contents into any winforms controls? I need the exact formatting of the word document along with any printscreens it has.

Comment: will it be the same as opening word document using winform?

Comment: No, I don't want to open a word document, I just want to paste all of it's contents with all of its original formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any Visual Studio native control to achieve what you want to do.  The RichText Box will not provide 100% formatting.

In this case you will have to find a 3rd party control.
The following is free and you have the sourcecode but it looks a bit old:
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/3582/word-control-for-net

A quick google search yielded these products.
https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/rich_editor/

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NevronSoftware.RichTextEditorforWinForms-12056